# Is there a way to return the nth document in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find the nth item in my mongodb collection, but I am getting an error that says:

```
    }).skip(r).limit(1);
      ^

     TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
mongodb.collection("Interview Questions").count(function(err, documentCount) {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentCount);

        let returnFlash = mongodb.collection("Interview Questions").find({}, (err, data) => {
            callback(returnFlash);
        }).skip(r).limit(1);
    });
```

I am trying to return a random document in my collection. I tried using async so I could make a function to do so without having to worry about using callbacks, but the server my school is using does not have the correct version of node installed.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit off. It should be more like

```
mongodb.collection("Interview Questions").find({}).skip(r).limit(1).exec((err, data) => {
        callback(returnFlash);
    };
```

Comment: Any reason why I would be getting ".exec is not a function"? I installed exec and required it at the top of the file.